# Make radio button and checkbox exclusive

Tags: jquery

Is any alternative way to make radio button and checkbox exclusive?

Except the below way:

```
 $(':checkbox').live('change',function()
 {
       $(':radio').prop('checked',!$(this).prop('checked'));
 });

 $(':radio').live('change',function()
 {
       $(':checkbox').prop('checked',!$(this).prop('checked'));
 });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mVWx6/) is a jsFiddle to work on.

Comment: why would you want to make in another way?

Comment: Why don't you just use all radio buttons?  That's kinda what they're for.  If they all have the same name, only one can be selected.

Comment: Only thing I could think of is to use the bind() function instead of live().  Live() is more for dynamically added elements to the page.  Out of context, I have no idea if you're doing that.

Comment: Why you people are using jQuery over javascript??? the same thing is the answer for those who are asking why you are trying new way and also for those who voted up that comment.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about in one line ?

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='radio'>
```

**JS**

```
 $(':checkbox,:radio').live('change',function()
 {
       $(this).siblings(':checkbox,:radio').prop('checked',!$(this).prop('checked'));
 });
```

Live demo on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/mVWx6/1/)